# Android Gradle Sync Error: Read timed out

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Facing this error when I **Sync** Gradle project in Android Studio.

> Read timed out

I have also tried as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605734/android-studio-gradle-build-error-read-time-out) but no luck. Everything was working fine until I updated my Android Studio to 3.2.

- Android Plugin Version: 3.2.0
- Gradle Version: 4.6

**EDIT:**

*build.gradle (Project:FOTS)*

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*build.gradle (Module:app)*

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.biocare.fots"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 29
        versionName "2.1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.10'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: You have extra `repositories` in the second `Build.gradle`. Remove it first. Except that, everything looks fine in my side. That would be great to see the whole error BTW.

Comment: Can you point out which are extra repositories?

Comment: Under your dependencies in the second `Build.gradle`. Try adding `mavenCentral()` in the `build.gradle (Project:FOTS)` repositories and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any proxy or firewall because may be a cause for build sync? If you are not using then choose menu item: File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to verify your internet connection first.
Check any antivirus or firewall, try disabling all of them.
Check if your gradle in offline, it should be online.
Ifnon worked, try using some vpns, It works sometimes.

Answer (score -2):

May I learn your download speed? Most probably you have unstable internet connection around ~20kbps when your IDE download packages. This is a shame what companies and communities like microsoft, google, jetbrains, npm doesn't care about internet speeds and doesn't give the opportunity to have offline packages to be sure make stable environement for developers with poor internet connection.