# How Can I Solve Android Studio Error: Read Time Out?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I open an existing `Android Studio` project (which is cloned from someone else), the building for sync project takes a long time and failed every time.

And the prompt message is `ERROR: Read time out`.

[image]
I am from a place where the network is not free, however, **I am sure that I successfully set up the proxy in Android Studio,** which helps me build a new project and use Google's services successfully many a time.

However, what should I do when opening an existing project? Thanks a lot.

---

**Other potentially useful information：**

```
Android Studio 3.3.1

Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5264788, built on January 29, 2019

JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Linux 4.15.0-45-generic
```

Comment: [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605734/android-studio-gradle-build-error-read-time-out/51417743)

Comment: I have read this article, but I feel that my problems is different from that, so that  still don't know how to do it. However, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who re-edited for my question or reply to me.
According to your answer, I know that both **Android Studio** and **Gradle** need **setting proxy**. Below is my solution.

---

- 1. Make sure the proxy setting for Android Studio is OK.

Select in Android Studio: `File` -> `Settings` -> `Appearance & Behavior` -> `System Settings` -> `HTTP Proxy`. And setting right proxy.

- 2. Add proxy setting for your `gradle.properties` file, and you can find it easily.

```sh
Project/
├── app
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
|
├── gradle.properties
|
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── local.properties
├── Messages.iml
└── settings.gradle
```

Add the following code to the `gradle.properties` file.

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=XXXX
systemProp.socks.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.socks.proxyPort=XXXX
```

- 3. Try to sync project again.

Select in Android Studio: `File` -> `Sync Project with Gragle Files`

---

**I don't know if the above method is good, but it works to me. I hope it works to you, too. Thanks again.**

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem before. Downloading dependencies failure is the reason. Maybe the problem lies in your network connection. Android studio's log may help you to locate which dependency can't not be reached.

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.